# Providing a figure for given problem

Tags: trigonometry

The Question is from Challenge and Thrill of Pre College Mathematics, Ex. 6.10 ques no. 8

I've been trying this ques for a lot of time but I've been facing the following problems

How can two points(at each end of base) extend the same angle of elevation. If they do their respective line of sight will never meet

Secondly if there is a typing error and it should be that the peak subtends an angle then the problem is how can a point subtend an angle.

Any hint or a figure of the given problem would suffice.

The Question is also present in the link below. It is ques number 4

https://www.google.com/amp/s/madhavamathcompetition.com/2016/07/10/heights-and-distances-ii-problems-for-rmo-and-iitjee-maths/amp/

Or the photo here

https://ibb.co/Cbs2BwX

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the two ends of the segment and the base of the peak are in a straight line, but this is not given.  Suppose the ends of the segment are at $(\pm1,0,0)$ and the peak is at $(0,1,10)$.

Comment: Yes i seemed to have missed that case. So it remains angle of elevation only??

Comment: Please at least summarize the cited link. Links go stale, not everybody is inclined to click around. Make it easy to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #4 solution
Let midpoint of $AB$ be $O$.

In right triangle $PON$ we have $ON = \dfrac{PN}{\tan\phi}$
In right triangle $PAN$ we have $AN = \dfrac{PN}{\tan\theta}$

Finally in right triangle $AON$ apply pythagoras :
$$\begin{align} 
&OA^2+ON^2 = AN^2\\
&a^2+\dfrac{PN^2}{\tan^2\phi} = \dfrac{PN^2}{\tan^2\theta}\\
\end{align}$$

Isolate $PN$ and simplify.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also got the answer using the thing which i  had proved above and changing it a bit. The expression which i derived above was a bit wrong and using appollonius now i got h=a/root(cot^2 theta-cot^2 phi) instead of root(a/(cot^2 theta-cot^2 phi)) now i wrote cot^2 as cos^2 /sin^2  now i took LCM and send the sin^2 theta.sin^2 phi up which proves the numerator of expression we want to prove. Now using some trigno formulae i proved the deno and eventually expression i wanted!!!!! If you have any confusion in my solution you can ask. By the way thanks for your solution i got a new way!!!

Comment: Nice nice congratulations on figuring it out! I'll have another look in the morning.. super sleepy now. You must have done simplification in the end like:

$$\cot^2\theta - \cot^2\phi = (\cot\theta+\cot\phi)(\cot\theta-\cot\phi) = \dfrac{\sin(\phi+\theta)\sin(\phi-\theta)}{(\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2}$$

Comment: Actually what you proved and i proved are one and the same thing :-)

Comment: Yes same simplification as you mentioned. Thanks a lot. Have a good night

Comment: In your expression if expression if u send second LHS term right side take PN common and write 1/tan as cot you get the same thing as i did. But I guess you may have simplified your expression in another short way. If I'm not bothering you can u tell me exactly what you did to simply your expression. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You can refer to my solution here.   https://ibb.co/31Rf8f7

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture to better understand the problem #3.

$PN$ is the vertical tower.
$N, A, B$ are on the ground on the same plane.
$PN\perp NA \perp AB$
$\angle PAN =\alpha$
$\angle PBN = \beta$

[image]

---

You want to show
$$PN = AB\dfrac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\sqrt{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)}}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97382/discussion-on-answer-by-ganeshie8-providing-a-figure-for-given-problem).